# jquery close div onclick except if specific buttons clicked

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="theHover" class="therequest" style="display:none;">

<div class="noprint"><button  id="closetheHover">Close Window</button></div>

All My Content

<div class="noprint"><button id="theprint" class="print">Print</button></div>

</div>
```

I want to close theHover div when clicked anywhere on the div except for on theprint button

I have the button closethehover closing it now.

```
$("#closetheHover").live("click", function(){  
 $("#theHover").hide();
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$("#theHover").on("click", '*:not("#thePrint")', function(){  
    $("#theHover").hide();
});
```

[JS Fiddle proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hRMgk/).

Note that `live()`. has been deprecated as of jQuery 1.7. If you're using a version *prior* to 1.7, the API recommends using `delegate()`, or in 1.7 and above, use `on()`.

References:

- [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Good to know about the on(), will have to update when I move to the new verion.  delegate() didn't work for me, but I did use this one with live() for now.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).on("click", "#closetheHover", function(e){  
    if (e.target.id != 'theprint') {
        $("#theHover").hide();
    }
});​
```

Replace `document` with closest non dynamic parent!

Comment: Worth clarifying: `e.target` is a DOM element, not a jQuery object, which is why `e.target.id` works.

Comment: Also: make sure you're using jQuery 1.7 or later to use `.on()`

Comment: Was just about to add that, 1.7+ is required for using on(), and there's nothing wrong in using the latest version!

Comment: Also also: replacing `document` with the closest non-dynamic parent only works if you're running this code after the DOM is loaded (i.e. at the bottom of the page, or inside `$(document).ready`).

Comment: @Blazemonger - if javascript is placed before the elements in the document without an onload handler, nothing will work. And without a jQuery ready handler, most of the time jQuery won't be loaded when the function is initialized, and won't work either ?

Comment: @adeneo No, writing `$(document).on('click', '#selector', function(e){ ...` is equivalent to `$('#selector').live('click', function(e) {...` and can be put anywhere in the page.

Comment: @Blazemonger - that's just a delegated event, and has nothing to do with it. If you place that code inside script tags at the top of a document without placing it in a ready function, jQuery will not be loaded at runtime, and it will not work, delegated or not!

Comment: @adeneo jQuery is loaded as soon as you add it in a `<script>` tag. The `$(document).ready` block is useful, but by no means required. I write events without it all the time.